# Error about journaling while running mongod.exe

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am running mongodb using command promopt on windows. When running the command

```
mongod.exe --config "config-file-path"
```

I am getting an error

```
32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
```

Can you guys help me in resolving this issue? What does it mean? What are possible solutions?

[image: This is how it looks on the console]

Comment: I put a little bit more info about the error in the title. And did a little formatting. And added a few question marks.

Answer (score 0):

It says your machine doesn't have journalling enabled by default. From Logs I don't see it as an error. Its more of warning or information kind.

If you want to have durability then use journaling option,

```
mongod.exe --config "config-file-path" --journal
```

If you want to disable journaling to get performance benefits then disable journaling,

```
mongod.exe --config "config-file-path" --nojournal
```

Comment: when I ran the above command it gave error  **I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files**

Comment: Since earlier error giving journal is not enabled that's why I am using --journal

Comment: Correct. Error says, it will start mongo from empty collection. It should not delete data. Check for your data once, is it present or not?

Comment: I simply put my mongodb server on windows C: drive and it worked. Earlier I kept it on D: drive.